# Node Space Dot Command Node JS

Tags: node.js

I am coming back to a Node JS script after some time. I am in my development directory/folder with many test JS scripts. I load the script that, by name, looks like the one I want to run. It has the most recent date which supports this point of view. I run the following command:

```
C:\testscripts>node .
```

It runs the script successfully. But I can't see how this has happened. My script is what's largely contained in [GoogleDrive for Developers Node JS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs) I look at the requires, scopes, credentials etc but can't figure out how my dev environment 'knows' which script to run when I use the generic command above?

So I can also run the same script using it's name.

```
C:\testscripts>node gdocToTextDownload.js
```

But what is it that lets me leave the file name out and still get the same result? I would appreciate a suggestion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node looks at the `main` field of `package.json` and runs the file listed there.

[npmjs.com documentation for `package.json` `main`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#main)

[Nodejs.dev documentation for `package.json` `main`](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-package-json-guide/#main)